# Simple regex doesn't work to validate numbers

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to verify if my EditText contains only numbers and if inside it contains a specific length of numbers.
I'm using a simple regex: `/^([0-9]{11})$/`

UPDATE: Inserting some code:

```
private boolean validateData( String dataToValidate, String dataPattern ){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( dataPattern );
        return pattern.matcher( dataToValidate ).matches();
    }

validateData(data, "/^[0-9]{11}$/")
```

And my EditText is setted to receive only 11 numbers. And yes, I've seen another posts on SO.

Comment: So what is your question then? The expression seems correct though you do not necessarily need the capturing group.

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you are trying

Comment: I think you just need `str.matches("[0-9]{11}")` or `str.matches("[0-9]{1,11}")`. In your code, `validateData(data, "[0-9]{11}")`

Answer (score 0):

You have two category validation.

> EditText contains only numbers

use: `android:inputType="numberSigned"`

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Number"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

> receive only 11 numbers

Now for the length use:

```
 if (etNumber.getText().toString().trim().length() != 11) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etNumber.requestFocus();
        }
```

if you want to use Regex (Second option)

you can use:

```
 String regexStr = "^[0-9]*$";
if (!(etNumber.getText().toString().trim().matches(regexStr))) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your edit text to receive only numbers you just need to set

```
android:inputType="number"
```

in the xml

For setting the input max length just add:

```
android:maxLength="11"
```

int the xml.

In case if you want to check if the length of text entered is 11 implement the following code:

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

@Override    
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int count, int after) {
}

@Override    
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int before, int count) {
  if(s.length() < 11)
    //your code;
 }else{
  //your code;
 }
});
```

In case you want to have regex matching do the following:

```
 String pattern = "[0-9]{11}";
 String testString = "12345678912";
 if(testString.matches(pattern)){
     Log.i("TAG", "Matches");
 }else{
     Log.i("TAG", "No Match");
 }
```

Hope it helps.